# Installed Ubuntu by Something else option erasing whole C drive where my previous Windows 10 was installed

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, windows-10, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu for the first time and replaced Windows 10 which was installed on the C drive. I always have to go to Windows Boot Manager and select Ubuntu to start my laptop. If I let the automatic repair go on it shows this screen.

[image]

I don't want to lose my files in D and E drives. I didn't find any similar problem in the forum (it's been 24 hours of searching now). To clarify more I didn't install the partition version, I completely erased Windows 10 which was installed in C drive and then installed Ubuntu on the C drive.
I tried to give Ubuntu as a default boot, but still, the Windows 10 automatic repair starts.

Comment: Does your machine have multiple disk drives? or a single disk drive (and had multiple partitions).  Erase disk and install Ubuntu will erase all partitions on the selected *disk* drive (a *drive* is a different thing to a *partition*, though microsoft have some historically issues some documents that did confuse this by using the incorrect term clarified only on their website which few people read)

Comment: @guiverc My laptop has only one disk drive and had multiple partitions. But I didn't want to lose my data from other partitions that why I installed ubuntu with something else option. I tried making ubuntu as a default browser but it still goes directly to windows automatic repair. Thanks for the reply, I didn't think I would get a reply this soon, kinda liking ubuntu community.

Comment: @karel I had windows 10 and I installed ubuntu yesterday, and also I am looking for a solution which doesn't require re-installing ubuntu. Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: I don't want you to reinstall Ubuntu unnecessarily. My intention is for you to repair grub without reinstalling Ubuntu. Keep everything in Ubuntu the way it is and only repair grub.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I found the solution, in the BIOS boot manager option under System configuration tab, there was a tab with OS boot manager label, in that tab windows was giving priority over ubuntu, so I changed it to Ubuntu by pressing F5/F6 keys, and yes it worked, now my laptop starts with ubuntu. But I still don't understand why is it showing windows at the first place, because I deleted it from the drive. Anyways thanks again for your replies.